# How to truncate char* after an specific special char in method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to truncate chars after an special character in my document id.

I have a search box where user can search file id, file name , and some combinations of file types and mane. 
I am trying to truncate chars after an special character in my document id.
I have tried strip and truncate methods but getting errors.
I am new to programming may be it is quite basic but not getting in my head.

```rb
def index
    if params[:search]

      begin
        @document = (documents.find params.permit(:search)[:search])
        redirect_to @document
        return
      rescue StandardError # rubocop:disable Lint/HandleExceptions
      end

    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it with split method

```rb
def escape
  @document = param[:search].split('#')[0]
end
```